# SQL CODE required to add a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query created to obtain columns-TODAY,TOMORROW,TWO AND 5,FIVEPLUS by using the below query:

```
SELECT COL1,a.COL2,DATE COL3,COL4,
       IIF(CONVERT(date, DATE COL3) > (CONVERT(date, GETDATE() - 1)), 1, 0) As Today, 
       IIF((CONVERT(date, DATE COL3) < CONVERT(date, GETDATE()) AND CONVERT(date, DATE COL3) > (CONVERT(date, GETDATE() - 2))), 1, 0) As Yesterday,
       IIF((CONVERT(date, DATE COL3) < (CONVERT(date, GETDATE() - 1)) AND CONVERT(date, DATE COL3) >= (CONVERT(date, GETDATE() - 5))), 1, 0) As TwoAndFive, 
       IIF(CONVERT(date, DATE COL3) < (CONVERT(date, GETDATE() - 5)), 1, 0) As FivePlus,
FROM [TBLBOOK] a LEFT JOIN
     [TBLUSER] b
     ON a.COL 1 = b.COL 1
```

I get the necessary columns as today, yesterday, two and five, five plus separate columns however, in addition to the 4 columns I want to incorporate additional column in the query as "Day group" with column data to populate the today,yesterday etc as the data for the new column using IF condition using the data in "date col3"as the trigger . I need this to insert one slicer with today,yesterday etc as compared to 4 different slicers. Hope my question is clear and if someone can please assist.

thanks!

EDIT

With above mentioned code I get the following sample table:

```
  col 1,col2,date col3,col4,today,tomorrow,two and five,five plus
```

I have created a pivot table and slicers using the above table data created through the sql code. I wanted to add another column name "day group" to have today,tomorrow,two and five,five plus as data for the new column. I was able to add a column using" if statement" in the excel sheet example:`=IF([@Days]<0,"Today",(IF([@Days]<1,"Yesterday",(IF([@Days]<6,"2-5 Days","> 5 Days")))))` but i wanted to use the above code to return the new column.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would *really* help!

Comment: I'm not sure I followed the question entirely. Can you show sample data and what you want it to return like/

Comment: Yes sure. With mentioned code I get the following sample:

Comment: Yes sure. With above mentioned code I get the following sample table: col 1,col2,date col3,col4,today,tomorrow,two and five,five plus . I have created a pivot table and slicers using the above table data created through the sql code. I wanted to add another column name "day group" to have today,tomorrow,two and five,five plus as data for the new column. i was able to add a column using" if statement" in the excel sheet example:=IF([@Days]<0,"Today",(IF([@Days]<1,"Yesterday",(IF([@Days]<6,"2-5 Days","> 5 Days"))))) but i wanted to use the above code to return the new column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to use is a simple Case Statement. Please find the modified sql.

```
SELECT COL1,a.COL2,DATE as COL3,COL4,
   IIF(CONVERT(date, DATE COL3) > (CONVERT(date, GETDATE() - 1)), 1, 0) As Today, 
   IIF((CONVERT(date, DATE COL3) < CONVERT(date, GETDATE()) AND CONVERT(date, DATE COL3) > (CONVERT(date, GETDATE() - 2))), 1, 0) As Yesterday,
   IIF((CONVERT(date, DATE COL3) < (CONVERT(date, GETDATE() - 1)) AND CONVERT(date, DATE COL3) >= (CONVERT(date, GETDATE() - 5))), 1, 0) As TwoAndFive, 
   IIF(CONVERT(date, DATE COL3) < (CONVERT(date, GETDATE() - 5)), 1, 0) As FivePlus,case 
  when CONVERT(date, DATE COL3) > (CONVERT(date, GETDATE() - 1)) then 'Today'
  when CONVERT(date, DATE COL3) < CONVERT(date, GETDATE()) AND CONVERT(date, DATE COL3) > (CONVERT(date, GETDATE() - 2))) then "Yesterday"

  when CONVERT(date, DATE COL3) < (CONVERT(date, GETDATE() - 1)) AND CONVERT(date, DATE COL3) >= (CONVERT(date, GETDATE() - 5)))then  "TwoAndFive" 

  when CONVERT(date, DATE COL3) < (CONVERT(date, GETDATE() - 5))then  "FivePlus"
  else 
   "" end as  [Day group] FROM [TBLBOOK] a LEFT JOIN
 [TBLUSER] b
 ON a.COL 1 = b.COL 1
```